# Rigify wont generate rig

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, rigify

I'm finding it impossible to generate my model's rig so I can animate it.. I've positioned the metarig twice now, re-imported the model as a much lower poly-mesh, checked the mesh's integrity and looked for any detached parts that aren't meant to be detached, and hid the separate meshes from the scene; (which I need visible and unattached for the animation); and it still throws this error.

Every tutorial I've found and followed waits until after the rig's generation to parent the rig and the mesh, but I did try doing that before as well. That resulted in just the circle with arrows at the model's feet, but no actual rig.

The only bones I deleted from the metarig are the face bones, and the only other edit I made to the metarig was for one of the spine bones. Before the NoneType error, it gave me an error that one of the spine bones was disconnected. In order to get that to work, I had to parent the ends of that and the bone it should have been parented with together.

I don't know what to do at this point. I've been bashing my head into the problem for going on 3 weeks now and have made 0 progress. I'd really appreciate some help.

[image: error]

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied your file and I see there are quite some edits you have made on the metarig. Just for comparison, here's your metarig:

[image]

And here's my version, where I only added the Cat metarig (edit note: you used the wolf rig, a little different in the names but that's not a big deal) and moved its bones around to fit your model:

[image]

(Note I hid the facial & fingers bones for readability).

See the bones `spine.004` and `spine.003`.
Their heads are in the same position in the raw metarig and in mine, but not in yours. If I separate them in my rig, then I get the same errors you get.
That's one of the things you must pay attention to: when two bones have their heads or tails aligned, you have to preserve that.

In edit mode it's easy, just select both spheres in one shot using a multiselect tool like the circle select. To correct it, you can use vertex snapping (but hide your mesh then) or cursor snapping with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (select one part → <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> → Cursor to selected, then select the second part → <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> → Selected to Cursor).

Fix the tail this way and it should work fine.
It works perfectly on my side with your scene so there should be no problem here.

If you need extra edits, then I recommend you to thoroughly study [Rigify's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html). It's too long to explain here but the manual does a great job at explaining how to use this addon and also gives tips on how to do things more easy for you and more accurately.

Oh, and... Please correct your bones placement x)

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: @LoLock (https://imgur.com/QD55mAj) I redid the rig and tried making the anatomy a little more accurate. The 5 spine bones in the tail was just one of the default bones moved over. The link shows the new (old, this was the one I was getting before the NoneType) error. Rigify generates a rig for only the facebones. The only thing I did this time was move the armature into place. And its a new file, like you suggested. How would I upload the file for further help?

Comment: you can use this service: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, here's the link to the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=0QD1ykzL" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0QD1ykzL/)

Comment: I edited my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Ok, so we definitely used a different rig, I was using the wolf metarig. I tried switching to the cat metarig and positioning the bones as close to your example as I could get it. I studied the rigify manual as well, but it only really gives instructions on how to place the human rigs. In the file given and now with the cat metarig, it still wont generate. Its now telling me spine_004 is disjoint and cannot be connected. I had this working before in the last version of Blender without any issue, I don't know what's changed. I add no bones, I only move, rotate, and scale the ones already there.

Comment: Oh! I forgot about the wolf one. But I think I know there the mistake comes from, check my edit

Comment: omg it worked :o Thank you so much for the help and patience with me! I'll work on positioning the leg and feet bones correctly. I have it closer with the cat rig edit, but the fingers are definitely still too far back. I'm guessing I'll just have to resize them because his paws are fairly small lengthwise, and I'm not sure I should be extending the finger bones into the claws. All I have left after that is to retopo the high-poly model to the low-poly and getting the separated meshes to move together. :) Thank you again!! <3